# Where can I find statistics about Android Enthusiasts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, statistics, meta

Where can I find statistics about  [Android Enthusiasts?](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

- [Statistics about the site questions and answers for the last 36 months](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/77392/statistics-about-the-site-questions-and-answers-for-the-last-36-months) (w/ graph)
- [Questions per month, top 10 tags compared](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/59301/questions-per-month-top-10-tags-compared) (w/ graph)
- [Questions and Answers per Month](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/59302/questions-and-answers-per-month) (w/ graph)
- [Most controversial posts on the site](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site)
- [Unanswered Questions by Tag with at least 100 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/77412/unanswered-questions-by-tag-with-at-least-100-questions)
- [Monthly new user signup rates with graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/77425/montly-new-user-signup-rates-with-graph)
- [Users with URL in their profile](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/42156/seek-and-destroy-auto-promoter)
- [Questions that have gone through a close/reopen cycle at least once.](http://data.stackexchange.com/android%20enthusiasts/query/17140/community-controversy)

Comment: How about some "cleanup" stats, e.g. "closed questions by reason" -- to see what are the most common reasons. Could be useful to figure out where we might need to polish our FAQ :)

Comment: @Izzy That would be great and it should be doable. I am not sure if I find the time to write the query, so if anybody wants to jump in, go ahead!

Comment: Unfortunately, at least from behind that corporate proxy I cannot run any query (all I get is some `{"captcha":true}` on an empty page here)...

Answer (score 1):

## [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com)

- [All Sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)
- [Android Enthusiasts League](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/54/week/android)

## Android Enthusiasts Monthly Stats Snapshot

````````````
 Month      |   #Q |  #A |  PA |  #U | #V/d | #Q/d 
 ```````````|``````|`````|`````|`````|``````|`````
 2012-09-01 | 9.1k | 14k | 86% | 16k |  25k | 17
 2012-10-01 | 9.6k | 15k | 86% | 17k |  27k | 20
 2012-11-01 | 10k  | 15k | 85% | 18k |  30k | 20
 2012-12-01 | 11k  | 16k | 84% | 19k |  39k | 24
 2013-01-10 | 11k  | 17k | 84% | 21k |  54k | 30
 2013-02-18 | 12k  | 18k | 82% | 22k |  54k | 23
 2013-06-25 | 15k  | 21k | 77% | 29k |  61k | 22
 2013-08-10 | 17k  | 21k | 75% | 31k |  60k | 24
 2013-12-28 | 18k  | 24k | 71% | 37k |  74k | 29
````````````

- #Q: Number of Questions
- #A: Number of Answers
- PA: Percent Answered
- #U: Number of Users
- #V/d: Number of visits per day
- #Q/d: Number of questions per day